# Aleinvault Connecting to central

Tags: python

```
 data={"size":"50","page":"500","sort": {"alarm.timestamp_occured": "asce},"range": { "alarm.timestamp_occured":{"gte": "","lte": "now","timeZone": "IST"}}}
```

when I am trying to fetch data from AV central , iam getting last 100 days data, I tried multiple ways to  parse data in Header but no use , changed sort from "ascending " to descending , and time stamp in different ways , can any one help me to get latest data instead of last 100 days data

Comment: OR can any one suggest me how to create Reports in aleinvault

Comment: could you prepare a [mcve] ? It's not clear what you're after, and what you're interacting with.